# listView adapter force close

Tags: android, listview

I don't know why but I am getting an error while setting the adapter.

ERROR:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

Even after referencing properly it is throwing the null exception.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lView);

        ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<>();

        for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ){
            item.add("Item"+i);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> madapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item);

        lView.setAdapter(madapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `lView` is null. Make sure it's in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: yeah..its there in activity_main.xml

Comment: You'll probably want to post the complete stacktrace and possibly that xml file. Then step through and see what is null

Comment: This code is perfect work i have check this code now..@Chanchal Roshan

Comment: edit your post to include the layout (with the layout file name)

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens in cases where layout does not contains the view you are refering by the specified id, check & change `activity_main` and change the Listview id to `lView`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to Android system unable to find the **lView** in the **activity_main.xml** which is used for the MainActivity.

Please check in other activity_main.xml files  layout, large-layout, xlarge-layout folders and add that ListView in that files if it is not there.

The layout will be picked by the android system based on the device, Then the UI components which are used in the code should be present in that layout.

Answer (score 0):

- on layout of **activity_main** has no View id.
  OR
- replice field `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with other items in line `ArrayAdapter<String> madapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item);`